# Multiple Queries as a Single Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Two queries

```
SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
FROM
  (SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
   FROM deodar) As foo 
WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
```

First query result will be taken as input for second query data for performing operations

```
SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM  deodar
```

After performing operation, I want to show the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can use a subselect.

```
SELECT 
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM (
   SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
   FROM
     (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
      FROM deodar) As foo 
   WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
) bar
```

It's not clear if you want the LEAD operations to be applied before filtering or after. If you want them applied before filtering, you'd reverse the order of nesting.

For more complex operations, or for better readability/maintainability, PostgreSQL (and recent ANSI SQL) supports [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) to let you create several virtual tables and select from them. The various virtual tables can reference each other—even recursively. [Microsoft has some pretty good documentation.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Depending on the SQL engine you're using, CTEs may not perform identically to subselects. In the simple case where a virtual table is used only once, a subselect is likely to perform better (if there are any performance differences).

A CTE solution would look something like this:

```
WITH bar AS (
   SELECT wavelength, reflectance 
   FROM
     (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber, * 
      FROM deodar) As foo 
   WHERE (RowNumber % 5 = 0)
 )
SELECT
   wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength) /
     (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
      AS reflectance   
FROM bar
```

Comment: "*and the planner will optimize it all into one big plan*" - this is actually not true for Postgres. From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html): "*The WITH query will generally be evaluated as written, without suppression of rows that the parent query might discard afterwards*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would still call the Postgres approach "one big plan," because it's not just blindly making a temp table—but you're absolutely right to point out that it may not perform identically to a subselect. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT wavelength,reflectance 
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) As RowNumber,* FROM deodar) As foo         
WHERE(RowNumber%5=0)

UNION

SELECT wavelength, 
   (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength)/
   (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = O THEN 1
    ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
   AS reflectance
FROM  deodar
```

The only condition to use `UNION` is that all the queries must return the same columns (types and names).

Comment: First Query result will be taken as input to the second query